# Controlling the size of circuitikz junctions

Tags: circuitikz

Is there a way to control the size of junction dots / open circles in circuitikz ?

It looks like `bipoles/length` influences everything including junction dot size; I want to keep the junction dot size the same but decrease `bipoles/length` and I can't figure out what causes the dot size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! It's `nodes width`.

From pgfcirc.defines.tex:

```
\ctikzset{nodes width/.initial=.04}
```

From pgfcircshapes.tex:

```
%% Empty terminal

\pgfdeclareshape{ocirc}{
        \anchor{center}{
                \pgfpointorigin
        }
        \anchorborder{
                \pgf@circ@res@left=\pgf@x
                \pgf@circ@res@up=\pgf@y
                \pgfpointborderellipse{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}
}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/nodes width}*\pgf@circ@Rlen}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/nodes width}*\pgf@circ@Rlen}}
        }

        \behindforegroundpath{

                \pgfscope
                        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/nodes width}*\pgf@circ@Rlen}
                        \pgfsetcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/color}}
                        \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
                        \pgfusepath{draw,fill}
                \endpgfscope

                }
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it! So nice to see the package is still used ^_^

Comment: +1 It works perfectly...

Comment: my biggest frustration with circuitikz is I don't know what things are called and I have to UTSL frequently.